# perform action at particular instant of audio

Tags: android, audio

guys am trying to perform some action at a particular instant of the audio which am playing using the `getCurrentPosition()` but its not executing at that moment.
here is the code :

```
public class Sound_image_comboActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.start);
    player.start();
    while(player.getCurrentPosition()==5671){
        setContentView(R.layout.main2); 
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: thats because when you start the player the current position is not 5671 and that statement only executes once and will not run while the player is playing.

Comment: i tried using while loop. still no help. suggestions ?

Comment: Also if you are attempting to change the layout on the screen at this instant you should not use the setContentView() method. You should either be starting a different activity or manipulating the layout that you've already set as the content. i.e. make things visible / invisible or add remove elements from it.

Comment: ya sir that thing came to my head. but its a bit tedious so i thought of changing the whole layout. is anything wrong with this sort of method? 
btw anything regarding the music thing? :/

Comment: you should not put the while loop on the onCreate method since it will never exit that method and for the system it will think that the activity is yet beeing created. I dont know exactly if MediaPlayer has a listener, but what about creating that while loop in your "onResume"?

Comment: i didn't get sir.. how to you onResume over here?

Comment: MediaPlayer does not have a callback interface that is meant for this use case. I think your best option is to use handler.postDelayed() to post a runnable to do whatever you want. If you know the timestamp within the audio, and you post the runnable right after calling .play() it should fire when your media is at the desired position. Any time difference I think would be negligible to the user.

Comment: hmm.. i'll certainly try that thing and let you know sir!